# ColdFusion 2016 Java ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, coldfusion, pdfbox, coldfusion-2016

I have downloaded the PDFBox jar file and have placed it under the `{application.home}\lib` folder.  PDFBox has a few other assistant jar files.  I have placed all of them in `{application.home}\lib` folder, too. I restarted the ColdFusion 2016 service.
In my code file, I have some very simple test lines.

```
  <cftry>

    <cfset local.pdfUnitObj = CreateObject("java", "org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel")>
    <cfcatch type="any">
      <cfdump var="#cfcatch#" output="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\cfcatcherr.txt">       
    </cfcatch>
  </cftry>
```

In the `cfcatcherr.txt`, I keep on getting an error saying, java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel

In `org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel`, there is a PDDocument class.  I have tried referencing `org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocuemtn` but it is still giving me the error. I have placed all those files under `{application.home}\jre\lib` and  `{application.home}\wwwroot\WEB-INF\lib`.  The error is still the same thing.  Is it because I didn't place the jar file in the correct location?  Anybody knows how I can get this problem resolved please?

Comment: What is `{application.home}`?

Comment: c:\coldfusion2016\cfusion

Comment: The error posted is because `org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel` is the name of the package - not the class. The class name should be `org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument` (note the spelling of PDDocum**ent**). Also, please post the full stack trace, not just the first line of it.

Comment: *placed all those files under ...\jre\lib and ...\WEB-INF\lib*  ... Don't place multiple copies of the jars in the class path. They should only be placed in one location, like `{cf web root}\WEB-INF\lib`. However ... having said that, for CF2016 it's simpler to skip all that and just load them in your Application.cfc file with [this.javaSettings](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/using-web-elements-and-external-objects/integrating-jee-and-java-elements-in-cfml-applications/enhanced-java-integration-in-coldfusion.html).

Comment: 100% agree with @Ageax on the `javaSettings`. Much easier to check the JARs in with your code base and deploy to servers instead of having to document for DevOps to remember to put JAR X in location Y should you need to upgrade or build a new server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Preferred method for CF2016+**

Instead of mucking about with the class path and having to restart the server each time, there's a simpler option for CF2016+. Load the jars dynamically in your Application.cfc using [this.javaSettings](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/using-web-elements-and-external-objects/integrating-jee-and-java-elements-in-cfml-applications/enhanced-java-integration-in-coldfusion.html). The `LoadPaths` parameter accepts an array of one or more directories (containing jar files to be loaded):

```
component {
    this.name = "YourAppName";
    // loads all jars in the subdirectories named "lib" and "ext"
    this.javaSettings = { LoadPaths = [ ".\lib\", ".\ext\" ] };
}
```

.. or supply an array of individual jar file paths:

```
component {
    this.name = "YourAppName";
    // loads individual jars 
    this.javaSettings = { LoadPaths = [ "C:\path\to\pdfbox-2.0.16.jar"
                                        , "C:\path\to\xmpbox-2.0.16.jar"
                                        , .. more paths
                                      ]
                        };
}
```

[Adrian J. Moreno also pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56997131/coldfusion-2016-java-classnotfoundexception#comment100530494_56997131) another advantage of this approach:

> Much easier to check the JARs in with your code base and deploy to
>   servers instead of having to document for DevOps to remember to put
>   JAR X in location Y should you need to upgrade or build a new server.

---

**Old method**

However, to answer your earlier questions, the most common causes of ClassNotFoundException are:

1. *Wrong class name*

   CreateObject expects a class name (cAsE sEnSiTiVe).
2. *Jar files aren't in the CF class path*

   Aside from the core JVM paths, CF only scans locations listed in `Server Settings > ColdFusion Class Path`. Jar files placed elsewhere won't be detected. (The default CF class path includes the `WEB-INF\lib` directory)

   Placing multiple copies of a library in the class path can sometimes cause errors. Though in my experience, that issue usually causes a different error.
3. *Forgetting to restart the CF server*

   Aside from the core JVM paths, the CF server only scans the class path locations on start up. So the CF server must be restarted in order to detect any new jars.

**Your error is caused by #1 - Wrong class name.** `org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel` is the name of a *package* - not a class. The class name should be `org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument` (**note the spelling of PDDocument**).

Comment: Thank you very much!  Wrong class name is the problem